# Pandas replacing one value with another for specified columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I need to apply a function to a subset of columns in a dataframe. consider the following toy example:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3], 'b' : [2, 3, 4], 'c' : [5, 6, 7]})
arb_cols = ['a', 'b']
```

what I want to do is this:

```
[df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x : 99 if x == 2 else x) for c in arb_cols]
```

But this is bad syntax. Is it possible to accomplish such a task without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mask

```
pdf.mask(pdf.loc[:,arb_cols]==2,99).assign(c=pdf.c)
Out[1190]: 
    a   b  c
0   1  99  5
1  99   3  6
2   3   4  7
```

Or with assign

```
pdf.assign(**pdf.loc[:,arb_cols].mask(pdf.loc[:,arb_cols]==2,99))
Out[1193]: 
    a   b  c
0   1  99  5
1  99   3  6
2   3   4  7
```

Comment: i'd be interested in the solution to the future warning that seems to have developed recently: `Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.`

Comment: @MikePalmice which one give back the warning mse?

Comment: oh, sorry. I opted for the `mask` solution

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `pd.Series.apply` when you can use vectorised functions.

For example, the below should be efficient for larger dataframes even though there is an outer loop:

```
for col in arb_cols:
    pdf.loc[pdf[col] == 2, col] = 99
```

Another option it to use `pd.DataFrame.replace`:

```
pdf[arb_cols] = pdf[arb_cols].replace(2, 99)
```

Yet another option is to use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
pdf[arb_cols] = np.where(pdf[arb_cols] == 2, 99, pdf[arb_cols])
```

Comment: so this is faster than apply even though it uses a for loop? very interesting

Comment: Yes that's true. Apply is just a thinly veiled loop.

Comment: would it be possible or desirable to use list comprehension to reduce this to one line?

Answer (score 0):

For this case it would probably be better to use `applymap` if you need to apply a custom function

```
pdf[arb_cols] = pdf[arb_cols].applymap(lambda x : 99 if x == 2 else x)
```